# How to make an NSURL that contains a | (pipe character)?

Tags: iphone, nsurl

I am trying to access google maps' forward geocoding service from my iphone app.
When i try to make an NSURL from a string with a pipe in it I just get a nil pointer.

```
NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6th+and+pine&bounds=37.331689,-122.030731|37.331689,-122.030731&sensor=false"];
```

I dont see any other way in the google api to send bounds coordinates with out a pipe.
Any ideas about how I can do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated, you should use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`.

Swift answer:

```
let rawUrlStr = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6th+and+pine&bounds=37.331689,-122.030731|37.331689,-122.030731&sensor=false";
let urlEncoded = rawUrlStr.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
let url = NSURL(string: urlEncoded)
```

Edit: Swift 3 answer:

```
let rawUrlStr = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6th+and+pine&bounds=37.331689,-122.030731|37.331689,-122.030731&sensor=false";
if let urlEncoded = rawUrlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlEncoded)
}
```

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried replacing the pipe with `%7C` (the URL encoded value for the char `|`)?

Comment: Doesn't NSString have a – stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: method that does that for you?

Comment: doh. that is exactly what i needed, just didnt know about percent escapes besides %20.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be safe for whatever weird characters you will put in the future, use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method to make the string "URL-Friendly"...

```
NSString *rawUrlStr = @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6th+and+pine&bounds=37.331689,-122.030731|37.331689,-122.030731&sensor=false";
NSString *urlStr = [rawUrlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
```