# Adding bounds to google maps search string causes nil results

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I added a search box to my mapping app a little while back which was doing very simple address searching with minimal options.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sydney+grove&sensor=true

I've just added bounds parameters using the current screen viewport like this

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sydney+grove&bounds=51.198083,-0.830125|51.799930,0.576125&sensor=true

it returns a result when pasted into a browser but always a nil result if entered in code (jsonResponse always equals nil)

```
-(void)  doGeocodingBasedOnStringUsingGoogle:(NSString*) searchString {

    GMSCoordinateBounds* bounds=[[self datasource] searchBounds];

    //CREATE LOOKUP STRING
    NSString *lookUpString = [NSString
    stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
                       address=%@&bounds=%f,%f|%f,%f&sensor=true",
                              searchString,
                              bounds.southWest.latitude,
                              bounds.southWest.longitude,
                              bounds.northEast.latitude,
                              bounds.northEast.longitude];
    lookUpString = [lookUpString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                           withString:@"+"];

    //SEARCH FOR RESULTS
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonResponse = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lookUpString]];
        if (jsonResponse) {

        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        self.searchResults = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"results"];

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableview reloadData];
        });
    });

}
```

This code was fine before I added the bounds condition and is fine if I remove so I'm really out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace the | with a %7C, for example see here:

[How to make an NSURL that contains a | (pipe character)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040632/how-to-make-an-nsurl-that-contains-a-pipe-character)

As mentioned in the comments on the answer, you could look into using  `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` for a method to escape the URL for you (so eg you wouldn't need to replace spaces with a +, etc).

Comment: Right on the button. Replacing the lookup line with 'lookUpString = [lookUpString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]' fixed the issue entirely