# Convert String to NSURL is return nil in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsurl

I am trying to convert a `String` to `NSURL` and my code for that is Below:

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(self.latitude),\(self.longitude)&destinations=\(self.stringForDistance)&language=en-US"
    println("This is String: \(url)")
    var remoteUrl : NSURL? = NSURL(string: url)
    println("This is URL: \(remoteUrl)")
```

And console prints something like this:

```
This is String: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-34.4232722,150.8865837&destinations=-34.4250728,150.89314939999997|-34.4356434,150.8858692|-34.4250728,150.89314939999997|-34.4356434,150.8858692|-34.4250728,150.89314939999997|-34.4356434,150.8858692|-34.423234,150.88658899999996|-34.423234,150.88658899999996|-34.428251,150.899673|-34.4257439,150.89870229999997|-34.423234,150.88658899999996|-34.4257439,150.89870229999997|-34.425376,150.89388299999996&language=en-US

This is URL: nil
```

The `remoteUrl` is `nil` and I don't know what is the problem here.

After that I try sort `String` like this:

```
var url : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-34.4232722,150.8865837&destinations=-34.4250728,150.89314939999997&language=en-US"
    println("This is String: \(url)")
    var remoteUrl : NSURL? = NSURL(string: url)
    println("This is URL: \(remoteUrl)")
```

And console prints:

```
This is String: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-34.4232722,150.8865837&destinations=-34.4250728,150.89314939999997&language=en-US
This is URL: Optional(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-34.4232722,150.8865837&destinations=-34.4250728,150.89314939999997&language=en-US)
```

This is working fine.

So can anybody please tell me what is wrong with my first case?

Comment: Did you try to escape the characters for use in urls?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040632/how-to-make-an-nsurl-that-contains-a-pipe-character.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As suggested by the Martin R, I see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040632/how-to-make-an-nsurl-that-contains-a-pipe-character) post and I converted that objective-c code to swift and I got this code:

```
var url : NSString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(self.latitud‌​e),\(self.longitude)&destinations=\(self.stringForDistance)&language=en-US" 
var urlStr : NSString = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! 
var searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr)! 
println(searchURL)
```

and this is working correctly.

For swift 3.0:

```
let url : NSString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(self.latitud‌​e),\(self.longitude)&destinations=\(self.stringForDistance)&language=en-US"
let urlStr : NSString = url.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString
let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!
print(searchURL)
```

Comment: `let urlStr = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())`

Comment: let urlStr =  url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

Comment: This fixed a problem that I began seeing with Swift 3. Not sure why my `urlStr` was able to get through in Swift 2.2, but adding `.addingPercentEncoding...` fixed it.

Comment: One suggestion is to safely unwrap the url just in case it has garbage data or nil in it. Use "guard let" or "if let" syntax to do so. Check my answer below for more information

Comment: The above solution in ObjC 
`[url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharact‌​erSet.URLQueryAllowe‌​dCharacterSet];`

Comment: @Richie How can i covert this type of string into URL. File saved with Chinese character. /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5F160C54-414A-4741-BDE5-4B5C0126F026/Documents/從出差錯.csv . I am opening URL with webview and it is working fine with english but not for other languages.

Answer (score 44):

as blwinters said, in **Swift 3.0** use

```
URL(string: urlPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
```

Comment: Thanks Man! This helped me in passing sd_setImage String with URL. It worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think try this it's perfectly work for me

```
  var url : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-34.4232722,150.8865837&destinations=-34.4250728,150.89314939999997&language=en-US"
        println("This is String: \(url)")
        var urlStr : NSString = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var remoteUrl : NSURL? = NSURL(string: url)
        println("This is URL: \(remoteUrl!)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get following error if NSURL is null and trying load http URL over web view:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

To be safe we should use:

```
 var urlStr = strLink!.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

if var url = NSURL(string: urlStr!){
    println(self.strLink!)

    self.webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

}
```

Comment: This isn't safe. The first line would crash if the optional strLink is nil. As would self.webView.

Comment: Expecting that strlink is not null as well as if not sure need to place condition for that.

Answer (score 2):

this work for me

```
let url : NSString = MyUrls.baseUrl + self.url_file_open as NSString
let urlStr : NSString = url.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString
if let url = URL(string: urlStr as String) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    self.businessPlanView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3.0

A safe way to fix a bad string being converted to NSURL is by unwrapping the urlPath string variable using "guard let"

```
guard let url = NSURL(string: urlPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
            else
            {
                print("Couldn't parse myURL = \(urlPath)")
                return
            }
```

The variable called "urlPath" in my above example would be the url string you have already declared somewhere else in your code.

I came across this answer because randomly I was getting the nil error with XCode breaking at the point my string was made into a NSURL. No logic as to why it was random even when I printed the url's they would look fine. As soon as I added the .addingPercentEncoding it was back working without any issues whatsoever.

tl;dr For anyone reading this, try my above code and swap out "urlPath" for your own local string url.

Comment: Note that this can only be used inside functions/closures