# how do i convert image string into url using swift?When I am converting string in to URL, i am getting nill value in URL

Tags: swift

I am converting image string in to URL, but when i am converting it I am getting nill vaalue in URL.
This is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tbldata: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tbldata.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceCheckCell", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCheckTableViewCell
               cell.selectionStyle = .none

    //save image in imagestr
               let imagestr = (self.data[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey:"service_image") as? String

                let URLString = imagestr
    //convert URLSting into URL
                let URL = NSURL(string: URLString!)
                cell.service_image.hnk_setImageFromURL(URL! as URL )

                return cell
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514622/convert-string-to-nsurl-is-return-nil-in-swift/28514901#28514901

Comment: Try printing your image URL, if its not in the right format it wont be converted into a url

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to convert a string to a URL is

```
let url = URL(string: URLString)
```

Do not use NSURL as you did above, it should still work but it is preferred to use URL as it is a struct and is thread safer to use.

However, this still may return nil if the URLString cannot form a valid URL

> Returns nil if a URL cannot be formed with the string (for example, if
>   the string contains characters that are illegal in a URL, or is an
>   empty string).

So you could use something such as

```
if let url = URL(string: URLString) {
  cell.service_image.hnk_setImageFromURL(URL! as URL ) 
} else {
   // fix your string perhaps it needs percent encoding
  fatalError("Check your source data")
}
```

Comment: You are correct, not deprecated but it is encouraged to use newer non-NS i.e. Structs rather than Class where possible.